# retrieve a character encoded portion of the uri?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter php framework.  I have a url that looks like this:

www.mydomain.com/controller/function/param

however, when the param value has encoded characters such as 'plus%2b' all that I can see (by checking the parameter) is 'plus'.  So basically I am loosing all encoded characters and anything that may occur after them.  I tried accessing the uri string directly using `$this->uri->segment(n)` but got the same issue.

How can I preserve encoded values so that if the url looks like: www.mydomain.com/controller/function/plus%2b, I get the string 'plus+'?

Comment: Why would you need those characters in your url?

Answer (score 1):

I think in config.php there is a whitelist of allowed characters (permitted_uri_chars), so you probably would need to add the additional characters here.

Comment: I checked this, but the % symbol is allowed.  I tried entering a character not on the whitelist and I get a warning so I know this is not the issue...thanks for the suggestion though